# Segmentation fault core dump in Fortran executable file ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am running executable fortran file on Ubuntu but after few seconds, execution terminates with error segmentation fault core dumped. This file works in my colleague PC but not on mine . I don't have source code of that executable file. I tried ulimit but still segmentation fault error exists. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not enough information in your question for anyone to give you a useful answer.

Comment: Running my fortran executable file  on Ubuntu like ./myfilename   gives segmentation error after running few seconds. I increased stack size through ulimit but no affect on error